# How to achieve transparent image placeholder in a CoordinatorLayout in android

Tags: android, transparent, android-coordinatorlayout

Can someone help on how to achieve this transparent upper section of an activity? I know that this uses `CoordinatorLayout` because the app that I am currently developing looks closely to this. However, when I try to set the `ImageView` or even the placeholder itself to transparent, it will only show white background. The fragment that calls the activity is not visible at the back. I even tried using the `android:alpha="0"` xml attribute but still i failed to get what I wanted to achieve. By the way, the image that you see below is the User Profile Portion of Play Store.

[image: Play Store User Profile]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Transparent Activity in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Comment: It's not completely a transparent activity. The portion that you see there on the uploaded image that is transparent is mostly an `ImageView` when you are implementing `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: Might be a modal `BottomSheet` from the support library: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Comment: @AlexLockwood I looked into that and tried however I was not able to get what i wanted. Have you tried doing that as well?